# Convert JavaScript date to Swift JSON timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate format

Tags: javascript, swift, typescript, date

Given a JavaScript date, how can I convert this to the same format as Swift JSON encoding?

e.g. I would like to get a value of `620102769.132999` for the date `2020-08-26 02:46:09`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Swift JSON encoding outputs a value which is the number of seconds that have passed since `ReferenceDate`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/2895363-dateencodingstrategy

It seems `ReferenceDate` is `00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001`.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1409769-init

```js
function dateToSwiftInterval(date: Date): number {
    const referenceDate = Date.UTC(2001,0,1);
    const timeSpanMs = (date - referenceDate);
    return timeSpanMs / 1000;
}
```

```js
const myDate = new Date(1598366769000);
console.log(dateToSwiftValue(myDate)); // 620102769
```

Comment: Please don't encourage using the built–in parser to create Dates. It's not obvious that '2001-01-01' is parsed as UTC (the new [Temporal object](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/) will treat it as local, as it should always have been), and  '2020-08-26 02:46:09' is treated as an invalid date in some implementations (because it's not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent). Oh, given the multiple language tags in the OP, it would be good to label the code as typescript. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As Elwyn says, Swift represents dates as time intervals that are seconds since 1 Jan 2001 UTC. Javascript Dates use milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC, so all you need to do is adjust by the reference date difference and divide by 1000, e.g.

```js
// Javascript function to convert a Date to a Swift time interval
// date is a Javascript Date, defaults to current date and time
function toSwiftTI(date = new Date()) {
  return (date - Date.UTC(2001,0,1)) / 1000;
}

console.log(toSwiftTI());
```

Since the time difference is a constant, 978307200000, you might just use that instead of calculating it every time, so:

```
return (date - 978307200000) / 1000;
```

Going the other way, just multiply by 1,000 and add the constant:

```js
function swiftToDate(ti) {
  return new Date(ti * 1000 + 978307200000);
}

console.log(swiftToDate(620102769.132999).toISOString());
```